# Is it possible to float the GLIMPSE Heads Up Display (HUD) bar top left, instead of bottom right of the browser window?

Tags: glimpse

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5

Love Glimpse, but finding the bottom right location frustrating, as it can disappear, and only by resizing the browser window, does it reappear again. May be to do with my master page and layers, not sure

So can one have the HUD appear top left.

Probably a simple html/ config issue.

Many thanks,

**EDIT**

Perhaps, on reflection this is not possible, as the detailed panes pop upwards, so no room. Would have to be a Heads Down Display :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently its not really possible because of the design (as per your edit). But v2 of Glimpse should allow for such changes to occur as the design is different and should allow for this flexibility.

Comment: When is V2 due for release? Excellent product by the way. I believe you are pretty involved in this project !!